# How to make a troll attack

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, post-production

So, I have a film I'm working on, and I have a fight between a troll and a couple normal sized humans. I have the humans down, but I'm stuck at the idea stage for the troll.

I have a lot of different whoosh sounds, but they are smaller objects, plus they are quite light and fast sounding. The troll would be moving slower and moving a lot more air, so I'm trying to think of where to start.

I haven't tried much yet, but my ideas include just slowing down the whooshes I already have, or recording a shovel or something wide like that.

I just thought I'd ask if there was a better idea I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

Troll = large,heavy,slow. I would be starting with organic sounds of large animals and objects recorded at high sampling rates, then look at pitch-changing or time-warping them to a lower pitch to get the weight in the sound.